# Why is the fugacity of a pure component not equal to the pressure calculated by an equation of state for that pure component?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase

I don't get why fugacity coefficients, $\phi = f/p$, of pure components are usually calculated via integrating an eos over a pressure or volume range. For example, when using a pressure explicit eos (such as the Virial-Eos for example), one can write:
$$
RT \ln \phi = \int_0^p(v-\frac{RT}{p})dp
$$
I was wondering, when we already know the real gas parameters such as the Virial-Coefficients, for example, why not calculate the actual pressure straight away?
Isn't the fugacity some kind of "real pressure", with $\phi$ serving as a conversion factor, $f = \phi p$. And isn't the pressure calculated from eos (PR, VdW, Virial etc.) also some kind of "real pressure" aswell. But why are they not equal?

Answer (score 1):

No. Fugacity is related to the Gibbs free energy variation with pressure.$$dG=VdP=\frac{zRT}{P}dP=RTd\ln{f}$$So, $$RTd\ln{(f/P)}=\frac{(z-1)RT}{P}dP$$